# Text box in bootstrap/wordpress

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3

On my site (https://ibb.co/fzMYMF) I am using bootstrap 3.3.7 with WordPress. How can I insert a white text box in the center of my site (identical on every page) so I can fill it with text?

At the top left it says "SERVICES services available" - this is the text I want to put in the white box at the centre of the page.

Comment: add it to your bootstrap template and then put your Wordpress hook inside that.

Comment: Do you know the code i need to make a box though?

Comment: what size? Where do you want it? Is there anything else in that column?

Comment: About the same width as the navbar, but a square. It's gonna be under the header logo so in the middle of the screen. Nope nothing else in the column except for the text that's gonna be in the text box

Comment: Updated sentences so the question reads better.

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap, I would do this:

```css
body {
background-color: #283bdf;
}

.maintext {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 20px;
}

.sidebar {
background: none;
}

h1 {
 background-color: #ccc;
 color: #424242;
 font-size: 64px;
 font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 500;
}

h4 {
 background-color: #ccc;
 color: #424242;
 font-size: 30px;
 font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <!---YOUR SIDEBAR--->
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 sidebar">
           <div class="services">
              <h1>Services</h1>
              <h4>Services available:</h4>
           </div>
        </div>
    <!---YOUR TEXT LOOP--->
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10 maintext">
          <?php 
if ( have_posts() ) {
 while ( have_posts() ) {
  the_post(); 
  //
  // Post Content here
  //
 } // end while
} // end if
?>

        </div>
</div>
```

This doesn't look perfectly right because it's not in a Bootstrap template.